# How to send PolicyId to a REST API claims exchange

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I used this Walkthrough from Microsoft (https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-cyrl-ba/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-rest-api-validation-custom) to configure a RESTful API claims exchange as a technical profile in my TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml file. I pass various `InputClaims` like objectId, email, etc. It works fine. The problem is that I have more than one custom policies that use TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml as a BasePolicy and I want to pass to the RESTful API which custom policy is calling the RESTful API by sending the PolicyId as a parameter.

I tried to add `InputClaim` like this:

```
<InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="policyId" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" DefaultValue="{Policy:PolicyId}" />
```

but it throw the error that

> policyId is not defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define `policyName` as a `ClaimType` in `ClaimsSchema` so it can be referenced using `ClaimTypeReferenceId` in `InputClaim` in the `TechnicalProfile`.

```
 <ClaimType Id="policyId">
        <DisplayName>PolicyId</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
        <UserHelpText>PolicyId.</UserHelpText>
 </ClaimType>
```

Then, this will work:

```
<InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="policyId" DefaultValue="{Policy:PolicyId}" />
```

Comment: This is called claims resolvers: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claim-resolver-overview

Comment: yup, I guess the @user3090407 did not define the claim.